# How to render view from of a different controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, controller

In my project I have two controllers called `PropertiesController` and `FacilitiesController`. After creating a `property` in `PropertiesController`, I want to load the `view(form)` from `FacilitiesController`.

I tried to do using `render facilities/new` which shows an error(First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty),  as I have not initialized the argument(@facility) passed to form_for method.

I can avoid the above error by initializing the @facility variable in `PropertiesController`. But I have code in the `form_for` which calls method on the `object` present in `FacilitiesController`. I don't want all that code to be duplicated again in `PropertiesController`.

How should I render the view from `FacilitiesController` without duplicating the code?

Comment: It's means after create properties you want to view Facilities form. right?

Comment: yes I want to load the view from FacilitiesController.

Comment: Than after creating properties you can redirect to facilities new method it render form of facilities.

Comment: Yes i am able to redirect using redirect_to controller: 'facilities', action: 'new'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope below code work for you

```
class PropertiesController < ApplicationController


 def create
  @property = Property.new(property_params)

  respond_to do |format|
   if @property.save
     format.html { redirect_to facility_new_path, notice: 'Property was successfully created.' }
   else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @property.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
  end
 end

end
```